# Something like map but with one value?

Tags: c++, key-value

I use map for fast finding names which can be about 200 and always different value or position. So now I write this :

```
map<string, string> names;
void function( string name)
{
  names.insert(pair<string,string>(name,name));
}
```

So key and value always same. Is it good to use this or exist something better? I don't want to use vector because i often find names and vector always do this successively.

Comment: [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `std::set<std::string>`. Sets are like maps, but with no satellite data, i.e. they *only* store the key.

If you don't need ordering, you may also try `std::unordered_set<std::string>`, which offers asymptotically faster lookup on average.